Should an Epic Story Reward Count Towards the Carried Magic Item Maximum?
My character recently received a Story Reward from the Reclamation of Phlan Epic called "Friend of the Griffons" which gave him a Griffon as a personal mount that travels with him as a trusted friend and ally.
In the Adventurers League Season 14 rules, it states:

Blessings and boons count as a magic item of the appropriate rarity
for determining how many magic items you bring to a play session for
that character.

Although technically it's a Story Reward, should the Griffon be treated as a blessing or boon with regards to magic item carry capacity, and, if Yes, what would you propose as the appropriate level of rarity?

The griffon is neither a blessing nor a boon
Blessings are described on p. 227 DMG, under the heading "Supernatural Gifts". A griffon is a natural monster (in a fantasy world), not a supernatural gift. Moreover

A character might receive a blessing from a deity for
doing something truly momentous-an accomplishment
that catches the attention of both gods and mortals.

That is, a blessing is bestowed by a god. You also only can receive one blessing at a time, while you easily could have that griffon, and a blessing  from the list of blessings on p. 228. And while those blessings are only listed as examples, and quite varied in nature, unless the adventure says you receive that griffon via a blessing from a deity, it is not one.
Epic Boons are described on p. 231, as follows:

An epic boon is a special power available only to 20th level characters

The griffon is clearly not that. And while there are some other mentions of boons in published materials (for example, The Wild Beyond the Witchlight has a willow wisp that can grant magic boons, these boons are likewise limited to one at a time, and are a magic effect the character can use once in a given time).
So, the griffon is neither a blessing, not is it a boon. Hence, the rules for treating blessings or boons as magic items do not apply to it.
